# react native sdk 41.0.0 out of date?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am taking The complete react native and redux course on udemy by Stephen Grider. I noticed the package.json has the value `"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-41.0.0.tar.gz"`

I assume this means that the course is using 0.41 but the current version is 0.59. I know react native already did a major change from class components to functional components and hooks and made a previous course I started obsolete. Is there a big difference between 0.41 and 0.59 or are things mainly the same?

Comment: I am pretty sure that course was updated and it has some lessons that show you what are the differences between class and functional components

Comment: I just cloned the path he has in the course. Very confused now.

Comment: but, to answer your question, yes. There are a lot of differences. You may take the course and then get back and rewrite everything to be ready for the latest version. Also, the latest RN is 0.64 and expo SDK 42 uses RN 0.63. So even 0.59 is pretty outdated

Comment: So I think this is the expo sdk version (41) not the RN version. So I think it's actually up to date!